# Using Ceylon classes in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, ceylon

Is it possible to use Ceylon classes in a Spring Boot application? What would that look like - the Ceylon classes as a separate dependency, or could they be in the same project?

I've got a particularly knotty Java problem that would *really* benefit from reified generics and an absence of type erasure. However, the main reason I'm writing it in Java in the first place is because I want to exploit a Java library for interacting with *a thing*. I don't want to learn any more Ceylon than is necessary for solving the problem, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ceylon integration with java is really smooth, you can use all the springboot stack and use java classes and even libs (maven) without problems, I have a small project [ceylon with springboot](https://github.com/DiegoCoronel/ceylon-spring-boot) using Discovery, Gateway and microservices that you can use as example. Its not documented **yet** but if you know about springboot then I think its enough as start point for you. I hope it's enough , otherwise I am available to help.

- Its working/using ceylon from current development, I didnt try with 1.2.2 release.